# Whoami doesn't change in GCP after I run gcloud auth login

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am learning GCP and have the following question in regarding copying object into a bucket.

In Cloudshell I ran `gsutil cp earthquakes.* gs://welynx-test1` and errored out:

```
Copying file://earthquakes.csv [Content-Type=text/csv]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission
```

I am logged in via SSH already so I checked the identity with `whoami`

```
xenonxie@instance-1:~/training-data-analyst/CPB100/lab2b$ whoami
xenonxie
```

And then I proceeded with editing the bucket's permission:

[image]

I added an email address to the Storage Admin member.

I then run `gcloud auth login`, and was prompted a link and clicking on the link takes me to browser where I log in with an email address, and then I will get a verification code to paste back to SSH window, and then became logged in as that email user:

> You are now logged in as [xenonxie @ gmail.com]. Your current project
>   is [rock-perception-263016].  You can change this setting by running: 
>   $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID

**Question1:**
What I don't understand is: I still see the same `whoami` as below:

```
xenonxie@instance-1:~/training-data-analyst/CPB100/lab2b$ whoami
xenonxie
```

Because I added the email in bucket permission as Storage Admin, I am able to save object into that bucket.

**Question2:**

I believe it is not needed to be Storage Admin, all I want is to write an object into that bucket. What is the best practice to do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1":**
You see the same `whoami` because that command is ran on the instance's shell so it is answering the session on instance-1.

**Question 2:**
Yes, you are right. If you are using the principle of least privilege as Storage admin is a role with more privileges than needed is not the best option.

As the use case you describe is only to write on the bucket you can use `storage.objectCreator` or `roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter` depending if you need to navigate in the bucket or don't.

To get more details about the roles available you can check [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

**EDIT**

To see the Google Cloud Platform Account being used you can use `gcloud auth list` and under you will get a list of accounts and one will be marked as active. The one marked as active is the one being used.

Comment: Thank you, can you advise how/where can I see the new identity (the email address) is in effect?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: `whoami` would output your Login username using with you Logged in on the machine. Use `gcloud auth list` command to check currently authorised User/Service account on machine.

**Question 2**: Storage Admin permission is not needed. `storage.legacyBucketWriter` permission would be sufficient.

Hope this helps.